# Port existing C code to ARMv7

Tags: c, embedded, arm

I was recently given the source code for an audio decoder which executes fine with on Windows when compiled with MSVC.

I was assigned the job of porting this decoder (which is written in c) to the ARMv7 platform.

Since I'm totally new to this field, I'm not sure how to go about doing this. I have already googled a lot, but could not find much that applied to my particular case.

Any suggestions about how to pull off such a port would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it's just C code with nothing OS-specific then it may be little more than a re-compile. If it uses Windows APIs though then you'll have more work to do.

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate what you have problems with? Compilation? API calls? Finding a suitable cross-compiler? Something else completely?

Comment: Why dont you just take the code and try to compile it in an ARM ide and see what happens?
http://www.arm.com/products/tools/software-tools/rvds/arm-workbench-ide.php

Comment: Since the question asks for "suggestions", all the above count as answers IMO rather than comments.

Comment: Thanks for all of your suggestions... Its given me something to start off..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compile it and see what breaks is a good place to start.

ARM is a 32 bit target and off-the-shelf ARM based micro-controllers are invariably little-endian like x86, so there are generally few issues porting code.

If the code makes OS calls to Win32, or uses third-party libraries not ported to ARM, then of course you will need to remove those dependencies or port to the target environment.  Similarly if the code makes use of the PC based hardware, such as the sound card, that will certainly need to be adapted.

Code and algorithms that simply processes data should port directly if the code quality was sufficiently portable in the first instance.  Undefined or implementation defined compiler behaviour however will need to have been be avoided, since this is likley to differ between compilers and targets.

Comment: ARM is not per se a 32-bit target. There is ARM64.

Comment: @rubenvb: armv7 is 32-bit.

Comment: I stand corrected. It also seems ARMv8 can be 64-bit and will only appear around 2014.

Comment: @ Clifford: Thank you very much for your answer its given me a good idea about how to proceed. Thanks a lot. Soon i shall do as i said and post the problem i encounter and i hope u give me suggession regarding that too. Thanks a lot